Interpreter setup in PyCharm on docker compose and python2.7
I try to add interpreter on docker compose in PyCharm 2024.2.4 and got some errors:
Connecting to Docker daemon…
Building Compose service odoo10...
 Container odoo10-redis-1  Running
 Container nginx  Running
 Container odoo10_db  Running
 Container odoo10-odoo10-1  Running
/usr/bin/docker compose -f /home/pc/documents/pyprojects/odoo10/docker-compose.yml up --no-start odoo10
Finished with exit code 0
/usr/bin/docker compose -f /home/pc/documents/pyprojects/odoo10/docker-compose.yml -f /home/pc/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharm2024.2/tmp/docker_compose/docker-compose.override.85.yml run --rm --no-deps odoo10
Finished with exit code 1
-P: not found
python3: not found
/usr/bin/docker compose -f /home/pc/documents/pyprojects/odoo10/docker-compose.yml -f /home/pc/.cache/JetBrains/PyCharm2024.2/tmp/docker_compose/docker-compose.override.6.yml run --rm --no-deps odoo10
Finished with exit code 127

The docker compose file is fine, and I can run it from the terminal or by clicking the trinangle button in PyCharm when I open it. I assume the problem is that the container is using python2.7 (yes, I know...) and I need to somehow force pycharm to use python2 for it. Thanks for your help in advance
docker 27.3.1
docker compose 2.29.7

Python 2.7 is obsolete; the last release of it ever was almost 5 years ago.  You should update your application to use Python 3, which ships natively with MacOS and Linux systems – you don't need Docker just to do development.
